# C++ stack and scope

Tags: c++, optimization, stack

I tried this code on Visual C++ 2008 and it shows that A and B don't have the same address.

```
int main()
{
    {
        int A;
        printf("%p\n", &A);
    }

    int B;
    printf("%p\n", &B);
}
```

But since A doesn't exist anymore when B gets defined, it seems to me that the same stack location could be reused...

I don't understand why the compiler doesn't seem to do what looks like a very simple optimization (which could matter in the context of larger variables and recursive functions for example). And it doesn't seem like reusing it would be heavier on the CPU nor the memory. Does anyone have an explanation for this?

I guess the answer is along the lines of "because it's much more complex than it looks", but honestly I have no idea.

**edit**: Some precisions regarding the answers and comments below.

The problem with this code is that each time this function is called, the stack grows "one integer too much". Of course this is no problem in the example, but consider large variables and recursive calls and you have a stack overflow that could be easily avoided.

What I suggest is a memory optimization, but I don't see how it would damage performance.

And by the way, this happens in **release** builds, will all optimizations on.

Comment: Are you compiling a release build or a debug build?

Comment: what you are suggesting is a **space** optimization, but not necessarily a speed optimization.

Comment: If all the locals are too big to fit on a cache line, this becomes a speed optimization since you don't have a cache miss.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Reusing stack space for locals like this is a very common optimization.  In fact, on an optimized build, if you didn't take the address of the locals, the compiler might not even allocate stack space and the variable would only live in a register.

You might not see this optimization happen for several reasons.

First, if optimizations are off (like a debug build) the compiler won't do either of these to make debugging easier - you can view the value of A even if it is no longer used in the function.

If you are compiling with optimizations, my guess would be since you are taking the address of the local and passing it to another function, the compiler doesn't want to reuse the store since it is unclear what that function is doing with the address.

One can also imagine a compiler that would not use this optimization unless the stack space used by a function exceeds some threshold.  I don't know of any compilers that do this, since reusing the space of local variables that are no longer used has zero cost and could be applied across the board.

If stack growth is a serious concern for your application, i.e., in some scenarios you are hitting stack overflows, you should not be relying on the compiler's optimization of stack space.  You should consider moving large buffers on the stack to the heap and work to eliminate very deep recursion.  For example, on Windows threads have a 1 MB stack by default.  If you're concerned about overflowing that because you're allocating 1k of memory on each stack frame and going 1000 recursive calls deep, the fix is not to try to coax the compiler to save some space off of each stack frame.

Comment: I don't think that the compiler is allowed to put A and B in registers in the above example, because &A and &B are needed.

Comment: @Arak - Right, which is why I said "if you didn't take the address".

Comment: @Michael, Sorry I didn't see that :)

Comment: There are benefits to not reusing the address. It makes rearranging instruction order easier to do for processors that support it.

Comment: @patros - True - optimizing for speed versus size could introduce different generated code here.

Answer (score 3):

Why not check out the assembly?

I changed your code slightly so that int A = 1; and int B = 2; to make it slightly easier to decipher.

From g++ with default settings:

```
    .globl main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB2:
    leal    4(%esp), %ecx
.LCFI0:
    andl    $-16, %esp
    pushl   -4(%ecx)
.LCFI1:
    pushl   %ebp
.LCFI2:
    movl    %esp, %ebp
.LCFI3:
    pushl   %ecx
.LCFI4:
    subl    $36, %esp
.LCFI5:
    movl    $1, -8(%ebp)
    leal    -8(%ebp), %eax
    movl    %eax, 4(%esp)
    movl    $.LC0, (%esp)
    call    printf
    movl    $2, -12(%ebp)
    leal    -12(%ebp), %eax
    movl    %eax, 4(%esp)
    movl    $.LC0, (%esp)
    call    printf
    movl    $0, %eax
    addl    $36, %esp
    popl    %ecx
    popl    %ebp
    leal    -4(%ecx), %esp
    ret
.LFE2:
```

Ultimately it looks like the compiler just didn't bother to put them in the same address. There was no fancy lookahead optimization involved. Either it wasn't trying to optimize, or it decided there was no benefit.

Notice A is assigned, and then printed. Then B is assigned and printed, just like in the original source. Of course if you use different compiler settings this could look completely different.

Answer (score 2):

By my knowledge the space for B is reserved upon the entry to main, and not at the line

```
int B;
```

If you break in the debugger before  that line, you are nevertheless able to obtain the address of B. The stackpointer also does not change after this line. The only thing that happens at this line, is that the constructor of B is called.

Comment: There is nothing in the C++ standard that forbids or allows this. So, it's quite possible your compiler does in fact allocate the memory for B immediately. Other compilers don't.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably that the compiler is putting **both** on the same stack frame. So even though A is not accessible outside it's scope, the compiler is free to bound it to a place in memory as long as that doesn't corrupt the semantics of the code. In short, they get both put on the stack at the same time you execute your main.

Comment: Also know as: Don't try to be smarter than your compiler. (No offense)

Comment: I know the compiler is allowed to do it, but I still wonder why he does it :)

Answer (score 1):

A is allocated on the stack *after* B. B is declared after A in the code (which is not allowed by C90 by the way), but it's still in the top scope of the main function and thus exists from the beginning of main til the end. So B is pushed when main starts, A is pushed when the inner scope is entered and popped when it is left, and then B is popped when the main function is left.

Comment: The compiler is free to allocate A and B in any order on the stack so long as the constructors/destructors are executed in the correct order and location.

Comment: They don't even need to be on the stack.  If the address wasn't taken in the above example, the compiler could just leave them in registers and the function could take zero stack space.

Answer (score 1):

A big part of my job is fighting compilers, and I have to say that they don't always do what we, humans, expect them to do.  Even when you have programmed the compiler, you can still be surprised at the results, the input matrix is impossible to predict 100%.

The optimizing part of the compiler is very complex and as mentioned in other answers, what you observed could be due to a voluntary response to a setting, but it could just be a result of the influence of the surrounding code, or even the absence of this optimization in the logic.

In any case, as Micheal says, you should not be relying on the compiler to prevent stack overflows, because you might just be pushing the problem to later, when normal code maintenance or a different set of input is used, and it will crash much further in the pipeline, maybe in the hands of the user.

Answer (score -1):

The compiler really has no choice in this case. It cannot assume any particular behavior of `printf()`. As a result, it must assume that `printf()` could hang on to `&A` as long as A itself exists. Therefore, A itself is live in the entire scope where it is defined.

Comment: -1: *`A` itself is live in the entire scope where it is defined*. That's exactly why it's in a `{ ... }` construct, so it isn't defined outside, at the time the compiler encounters `B`. So the compiler **has** a choice.